# iOS Facebook SDK V3.1 delegate methods

Tags: objective-c, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

In Facebook SDK V2 there existed delegate methods to receive information ie when a user logged out the delegate method `-(void)fbDidLogout` was called. But I cannot find any information about delegate methods in Facebook SDK V3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From reading the documentation thourougly now I understand there are no more delegate methods in Facebook SDK V3+

Instead you need to inspect the `FBSessionState` enum in the `- (void)sessionStateChanged...` method.

Answer (score 0):

in latest version of facebook sdk,when clicking on the logout button we need to check one condition and it will be like below

```
-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
    // get the app delegate so that we can access the session property
  AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    if (appDelegate.session.isOpen) {
        [appDelegate.session closeAndClearTokenInformation];

    } 
}
```

here session is FBSession class object and it is synthesized in Appdelegate.

Comment: Yes you can do that but that is not what I was asking for. I was asking for a delegate method that let's me know when the user has been "successfully" logged out.